# Update array inside of Mongo document doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user's collection, each user has a subscription array of objects. I want to add another subscription to that array. I'm getting the new subscription, updating it with `findByIdAndUpdate`, but it doesn't add the new subscription, however it shows that the document was updated. I tried several approaches but nothing worked well.
Here is the last approach:

```
...
  const { user_id } = req.params;
  const subscription = req.body; // Getting subscription

  const user = await UserModel.findById(user_id).lean().exec(); // Getting user by id
  const { push_subscriptions } = user; // Getting subscribtions with destructuring
  const updated_subs = [...push_subscriptions, subscription];

  // Getting user another time and updating the push_subscriptions array
  const updated_user = await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, 
    {push_subscriptions: updated_subs},
    { new: true }
  ).exec();
...
```

Here are the logs of request body and params

```
// body
{
  endpoint: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/cQ6wlRJ8t-s:APA91bEjqdLMzQLsroJ7zHzdjrzoshdPD8IJy_iIeRa8qV_Yjt6N1jeMUtyMq73wSn9JJT-4WXr_8uwHXttj-XFxHPCPAOqgN7zALsmf_BeIRZowRBTRHf9YH8v3AlcaZXWAIQ0qJNdn',
  expirationTime: null,
  keys: {
    p256dh: 'BBPC5h1QnBMPKMfPacgJu_2RFT7LAejyINh3CvP4pamkrlERr06YpRlSb7RbTUOn6MYW4adG93KfdEWXz68F9iQ',
    auth: 'Zl3iaOdBvihXG2QVOb26IQ'
  }
}
//params
{ user_id: '5fedc679f414663c693cf549' }
```

User schema, push_subscriptions part:

```
  push_subscriptions: {
    type: Array,
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks good, you can do single query using `$push` instead of doing manual process,

```
const { user_id } = req.params;
const subscription = req.body; 
const updated_user = await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, 
    { 
        $push: {
            push_subscriptions: subscription
        },
    { new: true }
).exec();
```

Comment: your query looks good, might be you are missing something or verify user_id is available or not, look at the working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/86HDH13IcBj)

Comment: yeah, maybe the problem is something else :/ thanks for the effort anyway