# Can't update array inside of document - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Users collection, each document has an "push_subscriptions" property. The problem is that I can't add a new element inside of it. Mongo updates "updatedAt" date but my array stays the same. I tried several approaches, but nothing worked out. My last try was with `$push` operator.

Here's what I tried:

```
  const { user_id } = req.params; // Getting id normally
  const subscription = req.body; // Getting subscription object normally

  const updated_user = await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, 
    {
      $push: {
        push_subscriptions: subscription // Should add the subscription to array
      }
    },
    { new: true }).exec();

  console.log(updated_user); // But console shows that the array is still empty
```

Here is the User's schema's push_subscription part:

```
  push_subscriptions: {
    type: Array,
  },
```

Element I want to add to that array:

```
{"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dpH5lCsTSSM:APA91bHqjZxM0VImWWqDRN7U0a3AycjUf4O-byuxb_wJsKRaKvV_iKw56s16ekq6FUqoCF7k2nICUpd8fHPxVTgqLunFeVeB9lLCQZyohyAztTH8ZQL9WCxKpA6dvTG_TUIhQUFq_n",
"keys": {
    "p256dh":"BLQELIDm-6b9Bl07YrEuXJ4BL_YBVQ0dvt9NQGGJxIQidJWHPNa9YrouvcQ9d7_MqzvGS9Alz60SZNCG3qfpk=",
    "auth":"4vQK-SvRAN5eo-8ASlrwA=="
    }
}
```

Comment: your code looks good , can you console.log(user_id , subscription) ?

Comment: @AmirBenAmara thanks for attention, user_id and subscription are fine for 100%, I can update other properties, i just can't update the array.

Comment: Subscription is a object with it's props

Comment: ok  try  `user_id`  intead of `{ user_id }` , and  `push_subscriptions: []` instead of  `push_subscriptions: {
    type: Array,
  }`,

Comment: @AmirBenAmara you think that the problem could be the destructuring part? Because I can get the user_id normally

Comment: if you can update other properties with this id , i don't think that user_id is the problème , i think the initialisation of an emty array is the problem

Comment: Yeah I also tried to the array part but it doesn't helped either :/

Comment: I think this is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65532594/update-array-inside-of-mongo-document-doesnt-work) i don't think there is an issue in query, you need to check other possibilities of error except query.

Comment: can you add full document of that `user_id` from collection, that you want to update.

Answer (score 2):

can you try it with this piece of code?

```
UserModel.updateOne({_id: user_id},{ $addToSet: { push_subscriptions: subscription } },async(err,raw)=>{})
```

and update your model as

```
push_subscriptions:[
      {
        _id: false ,
        endpoint:{
          type: String, required: false
              },
        keys:{
          type: String, required: false
        }
      }
    ],
```

and use the command for update .
i hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, it didn't worked too

Comment: share your codes, or leave more details about your model and data you wanna add to collection

Comment: I added the data that I want to add to collection

Comment: i updated my anwer